# How do a get by id and navigate to edit form in another component

Tags: angular

i have a service in angular, i using httpClient, and i have two components, trucks and edit-truck , edit-truck is where i should perform save or update operations but now when i click my edit button from the trucks html in truck component i dont get any response , im using forms for validation , how can i call the form in edit-form component from the truck componenet so i can populate the form with an entity

```
service

     getTruckById(truckId: string): Observable<Truck> {
          let cpParams = new URLSearchParams();
          cpParams.set('id', truckId);
         return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/" + cpParams)
          .pipe(map(this.extractData),
           catchError(this.handleError));
       }
```

my truck component

```
export class TrucksComponent implements OnInit {
  statusCode: number;
  trucks: Observable<Array<Truck>>;

  constructor(private truckService: TruckService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.trucks = this.getTrucksDtos();
  }

    getTrucksDtos() {
       return this.truckService.getTrucks();
      }

  deleteTruck(truck) {
    this.truckService.deleteTruckById(truck.truckId)
      .subscribe(successCode => {
          this.statusCode = successCode;
        //  this.getTrucksDtos();
        },
        errorCode => this.statusCode = errorCode);
  }

  // i should get the truck from the service getbyid here then transfer to edits form
  updateTruck(truckId: string) {
here i should do getby id 
    this.truckService.getTruckById(truckId)

    this.router.navigate(['/edits'])
  }
```

this operation should populate a form in another componenet below is that component and forms , im new to angular so i might have a few errors, any suggestions please

```
export class EditTruckComponent implements OnInit {

  private truck: Truck;

  public truckForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private truckService: TruckService, formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router) {

    this.truckForm = formBuilder.group({
      truckCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(30)]],
      purchasedDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      descriptions : ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  // private readonly toastCtrl: ToastController

  ngOnInit() {
    this.truck = this.truckService.getter();
  }

  processForm() {
    if (this.truck  == undefined) {
      this.truckService.createTruck(this.truck)
        .subscribe((truck) => {
          console.log(truck)
          this.router.navigate([''])
        },(error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      this.truckService.updateTrucks(this.truck)
        .subscribe(
          (truck) => {
            console.log(truck);
            this.router.navigate([''])
          }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }

  }

  hasError(field: string, error: string) {
    const ctrl = this.truckForm.get(field);
    return ctrl.dirty && ctrl.hasError(error);
  }

  isInvalidAndDirty(field: string) {
    const ctrl = this.truckForm.get(field);
    return !ctrl.valid && ctrl.dirty;
  }
```

this is part of my truck html for truck component

```
<table class="table table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
              <th>TruckId</th>
              <th>TruckCode</th>
              <th>purchasedDate</th>
              <th>descriptions</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let truck of trucks | async">
              <td>{{truck.truckId}}</td>
              <td>{{truck.truckCode}}</td>
              <td>{{truck.purchasedDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
              <td>{{truck.description}}</td>
              <td class="text-right">
                <a class="btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
                   ngbTooltip="Edit Truck"
                   placement="top">
                  <i class="fa fa-bus"></i> <span
                  class="d-none d-md-inline"  (click)="updateTruck(truck)" >Edit</span></a>

                 <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteDialog">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"
                                 ngbTooltip="delete truck"
                                 placement="top">
                                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                                <span class="d-none d-md-inline" (click)="deleteTruck(truck)">Delete</span></a>
                </span>
              </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using ActivatedRoute : 
**Step 1**: [ routing.ts ]

```
const routes = [ { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditTruckComponent }, ... ]
```

**Step 2**: [ TrucksComponent.ts ] when navigating

```
updateTruck(truckId) { this.router.navigate([`/edits/${truckId}`])
```

**Step 3**: [ EditTruckComponent.ts ] We need to use ActivatedRoute form @angular/router

```
contructor( ..., private route: ActivatedRoute, ... ) { }
```

**Step 4**: [ EditTruckComponent.ts ] Get the id from the URL

```
ngOnint() { this.route.params.subscribe((param)) => { console.log(param['id'];  }
```

**Step 5**: Now you get the id in [ EditTruckComponent ] , call the service under using param['id'];

```
this.truckService.getTruckById(param['id']).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: i am using activated routes, my issue is when i click get by id i am routed but the edit for is empty it should have the details of the enity i called

Comment: did you subscribe to it ? httpClient returns an Observable